# File not uploading to S3 after SDK upgrade

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

I have recently upgraded (19 Feb release of SDK) the AWS SDK v2. The older version was very much old (year 2021). I found some breaking changes with this. I am not able to upload file on AWS S3 bucket.

**Configurations**

the default credentials file is present in .aws folder in my $HOME directory.

Consider following code for the file upload:

```
func UploadFileInS3Bucket(fileContent io.Reader, filePath, bucketName, contentType string) (*manager.UploadOutput, error) {
    cfg, _ := awsconfig.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(),
        awsconfig.WithRegion("us-west-1"),
    )
    client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)
    // Create an uploader with the client and options
    uploader := manager.NewUploader(client)
    cacheExpireTime := time.Now().AddDate(1, 0, 0)
    cacheMaxAgeSecs := "max-age=31556926" // seconds in 1 year
    // Upload the file to S3.
    uploadResp, err := uploader.Upload(context.TODO(), &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket:       aws.String(bucketName),
        Key:          aws.String(filePath),
        Body:         fileContent,
        ContentType:  aws.String(contentType),
        Expires:      &cacheExpireTime,
        CacheControl: aws.String(cacheMaxAgeSecs),
    })
    return uploadResp, err
}
```

**Error with this:**

operation error S3: PutObject, get identity: get credentials: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, http response error StatusCode: 404, request to EC2 IMDS failed

It was working fine before upgrade. Any suggestions to fix this ?

Comment: If you run `aws s3 ls --region us-west-1` with the awscli on that machine, does it work?

Comment: @jarmod yes its working. Its giving me list of all buckets.

Comment: @jarmod I have tried to resolve this using `awsconfig.WithSharedCredentialsFiles([]string{".aws/credentials"})` in LoadDefaultConfig() and it worked. Is it the correct method or am I missing something ?